# gdm-password's child process Xorg makes my computer sluggish after suspend

Tags: xorg, suspend, gdm

Suspend and resume makes my system sluggish. The CPU load itself is not that much (10 %), but it's more than noticeable, I see it only moving the cursor around.

Logging out and back in does not solve it.

Here is how the max CPU process looks like in htop, in its context (see the yellow line. Only ~3 % at the time of screenshot, but it gets up to 10 %):

[image]

An Xorg process, child of gdm-password, is what takes CPU.

As a comparison, here is how the gdm-password process with children look like on a fresh boot:

[image]

I've seen that with gnome as WM, and with xmonad.

What is happening with gdm-password on suspend/resume? How can I fix it?

---

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64

Host: 20XWCTO1WW ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 9

CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1185G7 (8) @ 4.800GHz

GPU: Intel Device 9a49

Comment: Interesting additional information: it's the cursor movement on the trackpad, that is sluggish. With an external mouse, it is fine, I probably wouldn't have noticed. Might these two problems (sluggishness of trackpad, gdm-x-session's hungry Xorg child) be unrelated?